# Celibacy - halal or haram?

Tags: halal-haram, nikah, sex

Recently, I've been considering lifelong celibacy for several personal reasons.
To my understanding, Islam generally deems celibacy to be unfavorable, but not necessarily haram, because some Muslims may be unable to marry due to financial, physical or mental impediments (eg asexuality). 
After reading **chapter 5, verse 87**, I'm inclined to ask:

Is celibacy haram for the Muslim who is financially and physically capable, and who isn't asexual?

**(Quran 5:87)**

> "O you who have believed, do not prohibit the good things which Allah has made lawful to you and do not transgress. Indeed, Allah does not like transgressors."

Thank you.

EDIT: Most of the responses to the linked questions imply that marriage is not compulsory for individuals who are financially, physically and mentally capable. How can this notion be reconciled with the above verse?

Comment: A major factor in determining whether marriage is obligatory is whether you are safe from zina etc.

Comment: In that case rephrase your post and let it sound more like how to reconcile between the verse and the permissibility to not get married.